# How can I add an IP address in a AWS CLI with out exporting

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, unix, aws-cli

I am running below command to ingress in aws-cli, it is working fine if I provide an IP address, but I want it to know the IP and pass it.
I was trying something like below but it is not helping

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-123456778 --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr echo "$(curl https://checkip.amazonaws.com)/32" --profile xyzzy
```

If I am doing below then it works but I want it to be done by above way.

```
IP=`echo "$(curl https://checkip.amazonaws.com)/32"`
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-123456778 --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $IP --profile xyzzy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-s` with `curl`.

Try this:

```
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-123456778 --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $(echo "$(curl -s https://checkip.amazonaws.com)/32") --profile xyzzy
```

Comment: hi@baduker I have tried this one but it is not working.

Comment: it is working like this
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-123456778 --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr `echo "$(curl -s https://checkip.amazonaws.com)/32"` --profile xyzzy